# Aggregation issue with MS SQL 2008 Parent-child rollup

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

I have a table that has individual ratings for customers.  Some customers have parent customers.  I'm trying to write a view on this table that lists all customers, with the count of their ratings (and their children, if they have children), and the average of their ratings (as well as their children, if they have children).  I'm banging my head on recursive querying, and have gotten CLOSE, but i'm having this strange problem with the "parent" ids, where they don't accurately reflect the number of their(and their childrens) ratings or the true average of their(plus their childrens) ratings.

See SqlFiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6c1d/2 for the example.  What I expect is that 18639 will have a ratingCount of 13 (being the parent of the rest of the customers), but my query is not returning that.

Any ideas?

For those of you who don't use SQLFIDDLE, here is the data as a starting point:

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ConsumerRating]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[ConsumerRating]
    GO

    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer]
    GO


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer](
        [cust_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [cust_rating_id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [image_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [about] [varchar](500) NULL,
        [Parent_Cust_Id] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ConsumerRatingCustomer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [cust_id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsumerRating](
        [consumer_rating_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [rate_quote_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [cust_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [rating] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ConsumerRating] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [consumer_rating_id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (18639, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (32887, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (33236, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (33515, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34470, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34489, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34587, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34588, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34710, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34934, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34935, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34936, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRatingCustomer] ([cust_id], [cust_rating_id], [image_name], [about], [Parent_Cust_Id]) VALUES (34937, N'186391st', NULL, NULL, 18639)

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ON
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (2068, 6845810, 18639, 5)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (2168, 6345810, 18639, 5)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (1599, 6494148, 32887, 7)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (1788, 6630226, 33236, 4)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4034, 8726778, 33515, 10)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4846, 9206561, 34470, 3)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4635, 9051031, 34489, 9)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4317, 8874479, 34587, 5)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4258, 8839973, 34588, 6)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4658, 9061441, 34710, 7)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (4844, 9206340, 34937, 8)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (1844, 9106340, 34937, 8)
    INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] ([consumer_rating_id], [rate_quote_id], [cust_id], [rating]) VALUES (2844, 9006340, 34937, 8)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ConsumerRating] OFF
```

I'm using a recursive query, with querying against a cte constructed from two customer-related tables (to get the parent/child relationship and the ratings into one set.

```
        with ratings as 
    (
    SELECT     
    consumer_rating_id,
    rate_quote_id,
    c.cust_id,
    rating,    
    c.cust_rating_id,
    c.parent_cust_id
    FROM  ConsumerRating cr
    join ConsumerRatingCustomer c ON cr.cust_id = C.cust_id
    )
    , RollupCTE(cust_id, parent_cust_id, rating)
    AS
    (
    Select cust_id, parent_cust_id, rating From ratings
    Union All
    Select A.cust_id, A.parent_cust_id, T.rating From ratings A
    Inner Join RollupCTE T On A.cust_id = T.parent_cust_id
    )

    Select cust_id, count(rating) as ratingCount,avg(rating) as ratingAverage From RollupCTE 

    Group By cust_id  
    order by cust_id
```

The problem is that my parent rows aren't showing the right aggregates.

```
    cust_id ratingCount ratingAverage
    18639   24  6
    32887   1   7
    33236   1   4
    33515   1   10
    34470   1   3
    34489   1   9
    34587   1   5
    34588   1   6
    34710   1   7
    34937   3   8
```

I know I'm missing a "distinct" somewhere or something silly like that.  Has anyone had experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first CTE starts by joining the ratings with the customer table:

```
SELECT     
consumer_rating_id,
rate_quote_id,
c.cust_id,
rating,    
c.cust_rating_id,
c.parent_cust_id
FROM  ConsumerRating cr
join ConsumerRatingCustomer c ON cr.cust_id = C.cust_id
```

If you look at the results of just the above query, you already have two top-level customers (18639) and 11 other customers that are related to each of those, which is where the total of "24" you were getting comes from (2 + 11 + 11).  So you can't build your final hierarchy off that.

You need to build a "closure" table of the hierarchy first, and then just join that to your ratings table:

```
;with CustomerRelations as (
    Select  cust_id, cust_id as Parent_cust_Id
    From ConsumerRatingCustomer
    Union All
    Select c2.cust_id, c2.parent_cust_id 
    From CustomerRelations c
        join ConsumerRatingCustomer c2 On c.cust_id = c2.parent_cust_id
)
select  cr.Parent_cust_Id, count(*) as count, AVG(cast(rating as float)) as AvgRating
from    [ConsumerRating] r
        join CustomerRelations cr on r.cust_id = cr.cust_id
group by Parent_cust_Id;

Parent_cust_Id count       AvgRating
-------------- ----------- ----------------------
18639          13          6.53846153846154
32887          1           7
33236          1           4
33515          1           10
34470          1           3
34489          1           9
34587          1           5
34588          1           6
34710          1           7
34937          3           8
```

Comment: Yes, this works - I was struggling with finding a "root" for this recursive query - the closure table is the set-based solution I've been trying to find.  Out of curiosity, where is this "closure table" method mentioned on the web?  I pride myself on being a pretty good googler, but couldn't find an example similar to yours.

Comment: I googled "hierarchy closure table" and lots of links came up.  Here is an example:  http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html   You may also want to look into "hierarchyId" data type in sql server 2008 and later, which easily allows you to grab all id.

Comment: Thanks!  I was searching on parent-child aggregate and related terms, didn't have the "closure" terminology.